# Error in column - Postgres (psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "sales_ind" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying)

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am getting the below error when trying to execute the below query in Postgres.

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "sales_ind" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying

HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Column name : sales_ind
Data_type : int
```

This column had the output of the below case statement:

```
CASE WHEN ((fl.created > fl.sales_date) = True) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS sales_ind
```

Could any one assist. Thanks..

Comment: Unrelated, but: `WHEN ((fl.created > fl.sales_date) = True)` can be simplified to `WHEN fl.created > fl.sales_date`

Comment: Use `... THEN '1' ELSE '0' END` to get the numbers as strings.

Comment: yep that's an error message alright, how did you make it?

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name that worked..

Comment: Another option is to remove the `CASE` entirely and return a real boolean directly (instead of `1` and `0`): `fl.created > fl.sales_date as sales_ind` - however you will need to adjust your code to handle a boolean value, not an integer